# Изменить цвет пользовательского выделения с помощью JavaScript'a

Tags: javascript

Вот код, с помощью которого получилось изменить выделение, но как сделать, чтобы оно затем убиралось? Не могу догнать.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    var selectText = window.getSelection();
    var rng = selectText.getRangeAt(0);
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    rng.surroundContents(span);
}, false);
```

Ссылка на [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jg4a909b/)

Comment: @Decode, уточните, пжст, что значит "затем убиралось". По таймеру, по кнопке, по выделению в другом месте?  
Этот код является не изменяемым? В плане, что обязательно нужно цвет в коде задавать, хотя это дело логичнее было решить классом? Логичнее, потому что класс убрать проще и все вернется "как было"...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я хочу сделать то, что в CSS делает псевдоэлемент ::selection, но только на JS.

Comment: Ну что, неужели никто не знает?

Comment: @Decode, вы хотите какой-то велосипед, при этом механизм будет явно не простым. Типа на mousedown начать выделять, на mousemove удалять/добавлять (в смысле обновлять) выделение, на mouseup переставать. При этом надо не сломать DOM, при этом надо уметь не терять выделение, при этом надо как-то избежать тормозов или "перегрева шестеренок" на mousemove изменять DOM - опасно. В общем, сто раз подумать стоит, а надо ли оно?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в реали не стоит. Но для глубокого изучения JavaScript очень даже и стоит. Просто хочу понять, как это сделать. Ну и сделать, собственно.

Comment: @Decode, изучение javascript тут ни при чем. Тут работа с DOM и возможностями самих браузеров. `::selection`, кстати, только в CSS4 включен, хотя многими браузерами поддерживается, в урезанном (в плане стайлинга) виде правда. Не думаю, что это хоть сколько-нибудь полезная задача для изучения. ИМХО, конечно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, так вы можете помочь?

Comment: @Decode, сделать или помочь с глубоким изучением javascript? С первым см 2-й комментарий, как мог. Со вторым надо самому постараться.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду «снять браузерное выделение», как только отпустили мышку — чтобы осталось только ваше искусственное жёлтое – то так:

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // для норм. браузеров
// document.selection.empty(); // для старых(?) IE
```

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/jg4a909b/3/).

Comment: Я хочу сделать то, что в CSS делает псевдоэлемент ::selection, но только на JS.